# Home buttons cancels UIView animation

Tags: ios

How would I stop iOS from canceling the animations I set up for UIViews when someone taps the home button during an animation?
In the above scenario the delegate's stop selector is called with the finished boolean NO.

Comment: The home button sends your application to the background - always.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  This is part of the application life cycle.

The finished:NO is a cue to tidy things up, including syncing your models and views together.

When the user returns to the app, perhaps months later, you don't want to dump them into the middle of an animation, which is presumably why it's canceled.  Give them a consistent view that represents the state either before or after the animation (depending on your application design and what the animation represents).